# How to get the authorization working on an HTTP API request (v2) to Dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I'm using this code to get a list of tags for a public image:

```
export TOKEN=$(curl -S https://auth.docker.io/token\?service\=registry.docker.io\&scope\=repository:fedora:pull | awk -F'"' '{print $4}')
curl -S -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/fedora/tags/list
```

But it always returns `{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/fedora","Action":"pull"}]}]}`

I wonder how to properly use this authorization. I based the code on https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1253 and my final objective is to get the full set of repositories and images in a private organization, but first I need to understand how this works.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1253

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a post I wrote about this:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/adventures-w-docker-manifests-78f255d662ff

```sh
REPO="https://hub.docker.com/v2"
USER=[[YOUR-DOCKER-USERNAME]]
PASS=[[YOUR-DOCKER-PASSWORD]]
TOKEN=$(\
  curl \
  --silent \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username": "'${USER}'", "password": "'${PASS}'"}' \
  ${REPO}/users/login/ \
  | jq -r .token\
) && echo ${TOKEN}
curl \
--silent \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USER}/?page_size=100 \
| jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'

curl \
--silent \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USER}/${IMAGE}/tags/
```

Comment: Thank you! it's using another approach, but it worked pretty good for what I needed. Thank you!